# Using different router for different subdomains in node.js with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subdomain

I want to use different routes in my app, depending on the subdomain in req.headers.host.

So I came around with this idea (extremely simplified example):

```
var express     = require('express');
var domain1     = require('./routes/domain1');
var domain2     = require('./routes/domain2');

var app   = express();

app.use('*', domainRouting);

function domainRouting(req, res, next){
  var subdomain = req.headers.host.split('.')[0];

  if(subdomain === 'domain1'){
    app.use(domain1);
  }
  else{
    app.use(domain2);
  }
  next();
}

//404 handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  res.send('error');
});

var server = app.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

domain1.js:

```
var express   = require('express');
var router    = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('DOMAIN 1: ' + req.url);
});

module.exports = router;
```

domain2.js:

```
var express   = require('express');
var router    = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('DOMAIN 2: ' + req.url);
});

module.exports = router;
```

But this does not work, the routes are ignored and the request jumps into the last 404-handler.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `app.use()` dynamically like that within a middleware. You might call your router directly with `domain1(req, res, next)` instead of `app.use(domain1)`.

Or you might look into using a module like [subdomain](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/subdomain) to make it easier to handle subdomains in Express.